# Stuck on Differential Equation (Tried Substitution)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$\frac {dy}{dx}=\frac{x^2-xy-y^2}{x-y}$$

My work:

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{x^2-xy-y^2}{x-y}=\frac{(x+y)(x-y)-xy}{x-y}$$

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=x+y-\frac{xy}{x-y}=x+y\left[1-\frac{x}{x-y}\right]$$

$$\frac{dy}{dx}-y\left(1-\frac{x}{x-y}\right)=x $$

I tried to make it first order linear  differential equation and then I also tried to make it exact, but I still had trouble.

I tried substitution :  $Z=1/(x-y)$

Comment: It comes off as rude to make a post so poorly composed.

Comment: @MikePierce Okay sir,i will do something right away about it

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\dfrac{x^2-xy-y^2}{x-y}$

$(y-x)\dfrac{dy}{dx}=y^2+xy-x^2$

This belongs to an Abel equation of the second kind.

Let $u=y-x$ ,

Then $y=u+x$

$\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\dfrac{du}{dx}+1$

$\therefore u\left(\dfrac{du}{dx}+1\right)=(u+x)^2+x(u+x)-x^2$

$u\dfrac{du}{dx}+u=u^2+2xu+x^2+xu+x^2-x^2$

$u\dfrac{du}{dx}=u^2+(3x-1)u+x^2$

Let $u=e^xv$ ,

Then $\dfrac{du}{dx}=e^x\dfrac{dv}{dx}+e^xv$

$\therefore e^xv\left(e^x\dfrac{dv}{dx}+e^xv\right)=e^{2x}v^2+(3x-1)e^x+x^2$

$e^{2x}v\dfrac{dv}{dx}+e^{2x}v^2=e^{2x}v^2+(3x-1)e^x+x^2$

$e^{2x}v\dfrac{dv}{dx}=(3x-1)e^x+x^2$

$v\dfrac{dv}{dx}=(3x-1)e^{-x}+x^2e^{-2x}$

Comment: ... which unfortunately doesn't get you much closer to a solution.

Answer (score -2):

It doesn't seem to have closed-form solutions.

Comment: Wao!!!.what will one do now??

Comment: Depends on what you want to do with it.  Series solutions, numerical solutions, qualitative results using the phase plane...